# How can I create component in Joomla 1.5?

Tags: content-management-system, joomla

I need to make pages in Joomla, and my template has my header and footer. I intend to use components as pages where I enter my Html code. How can I make these simple components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Component is major part in Joomla, you should clearly understand its ins and outs, have a look at this tutorial to get you started:

[**Step-By-Step Joomla Component Creation Tutorial**](http://www.vojtechovsky.net/joomla/component-helloworld-tutorial-guide-en.html)

Comment: The link lead to a page 404.

Answer (score 2):

This [tutorial](http://www.joomladevuser.com/tutorials/components) is the best I have come across so far.

Comment: This is by far the best one I have seen, i have been trying to learn these for a week until i found your link! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should refer this [site](http://www.mmleoni.net/joomla-component-builder). This tools enables you to build component from scratch. It will save lots of your effort & time.

Here is another [one](http://www.sanisoft.com/blog/2011/03/21/how-to-create-a-component-in-joomla/) which I just found.

Comment: Answers which just contain links are [considered bad practice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please summarize the content here (don't copy/paste) so the answer can stand on its own. If you don't you run the risk of your answer being removed, especially if the link ever dies.